# How to get Lubuntu to autorun the Minecraft server script on boot?

Tags: boot, server, lubuntu, minecraft, autostart

Today I am trying to make my server but i have problems when I try to autorun my script. I have followed this tutorial:

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Server_startup_script and the script works when

I type `/etc/init.d/minecraft start`  but on boot it doesn't wanna start please tell me what to do.
If something is needed ask me in comments :)

PS: I can also start the server with `sudo service minecraft start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cron special string @reboot. add this to crontab section

1. type `crontab -e` then choose an editor
2. add this entry `@reboot /etc/init.d/minecraft start`

Comment: No command '@reboot' found, did you mean:
 Command 'reboot' from package 'molly-guard' (universe)
 Command 'reboot' from package 'upstart' (main)
@reboot: command not found

Comment: @Anil you need to give more detail on _how_ to do this.

Comment: @RolandiXor if you can tell me how it would be greatful.. PS: This is my first Linux server installation and i think everyone can see this on the moment they read the question.

Comment: I forgot to tell you guys/girls that i also can run it from service  like `sudo service minecraft start`

Comment: @AndreyTsarev I don't use Minecraft or Ubuntu server, so I'll sit this one out :)

Comment: @Anil I can't get it working. I tried adding the entry to crontab -e and adding `service minecraft start` in rc.local(before exit). Can I see some logs from the boot ?

Comment: root's crontab should be used to use service. so use
sudo crontab -e

Comment: to see log /var/log/syslog

Comment: The Log seems fine but the java application is still not running: `Aug  4 00:44:08 andrey-W566U CRON[1176]: (andrey) CMD (/etc/init.d/minecraft start)`

Comment: The CMD runs twice because i have it on root cron and on the cron of my user and it still don't appears to be running it fine.

Comment: I cleared my log and restarted my computer and here is the log from the last restart: http://pastebin.com/bvFRLzuB PS:Very sorry for triple post

Comment: change your sudo crontab -e entry to see minecraft script's message(error etc.)
@reboot /etc/init.d/minecraft start >> /var/log/minecraft 2>&1

Comment: var/log/minecraft is just empty. Maybe there is some problem with the crontab. Shall I reinstall it ?